# Microsoft dotnet(DNX) lifecycle

Tags: .net, dnx

Im kinda confused about microsoft support and lifecycle in dotnet at the moment.

At the moment i have Some old class library that targeting "**.Net FrameWork 4.5**"

im using those class library in my new ASP.Net 5 web service.

the target platform for my web service are "**DNX SDK Version 1.0.0-rc1-final**"

for supporting my old library , i removed **DNX5.0** from json file and only **DNX451** remained.

also i changed my CLass-library build to 4.5 to support **DNX 4.5.1**.

after i read this article 3 days ago from [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1.aspx) , i find out they are droping

support for **.NET 4, 4.5, and 4.5.1**.

so the question is :  is it bad to build my class-library on top of dotnet 4.5 to get them work with dnx 4.5.1 ?

or im doing this in wrong way , and should start with new framework on libraries, and wait for dnx452 to get them works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end-of-support announcement is causing a lot of confusion.  It applies only to the *installed* .NET version.  You have to keep in mind that there are very few machines still out there that have a version less than 4.5.2 installed.  Practically all of them were updated by Windows Update.

So if you call Microsoft Support and you have an issue with a machine that wasn't updated then you already had a pretty big problem getting them to pay attention.  Because the very first thing they will recommend is "update to 4.5.2" and you'll have a pretty big battle explaining why that isn't possible.

The 4.5.1 in "dnx451" is the *api version*.  Distinct from the runtime version and also distinctive in practice on your own machine.  Since it applies to the targeting pack, the files present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies.  Have a look-see to get the lay of the land, note how all of the .NET framework assemblies are present there.

But they are **not** the assemblies you use to run your program.  They are special, they only contain metadata and no code at all.  Best way to mentally model how they were made is by assuming Microsoft picked a specific release build of the framework and ran its assemblies through a tool that stripped out all the runtime details.  Thus freezing the api contract.

At runtime you use the assemblies that are actually installed on your machine.  On yours right now that's very likely to be 4.6.1.  On your user's machine that's currently very likely to be 4.5.2, 4.6 if he upgraded to Win10.

So targeting dnx451 does *not* create a support problem.

Comment: Thank alot for your comprehensive response to my question. Best Regard